# Manage ASP.NET state on website for mobile devices

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I have taken over development on an ASP.NET web forms app that is 100% designed to be used on mobile devices.  Currently, the app makes very heavy use of session variables.  The mode is default.

```
<sessionState timeout="600"></sessionState>
```

It won't surprise you that the app is buggy, and much of it's problems have to do with session data being lost, or, the entire session being lost.

Just some overview of the app in general:

- No sensitive (security risk) data is stored in the session
- The data in the session is small, but mission critical.  No huge objects.  Just a few INT's (Id's, etc), some strings, etc.
- We have to assume that the user's bandwidth will be low, and that connectivity will be spotty
- The data is unique per user

One of my suggestions to management about how to make this app better is to stop using Session variables and to use something else instead.  I'm of the opinion that switching to cookies to store all of this data is a better way to handle this.  I'm aware that some users may disable cookies (even on their mobile devices), but if that's the case, we can simply inform them that to use the site, they need to turn cookies back on.

I thought about using query strings, but simply from a programming stand point (building links, etc) query strings are a pain to work with.

I've come to this conculsion after reading this MSDN article about the various ways to persist State data, and each of their pro's and con's:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

My question here is:  Are cookies the best alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are limited in size and aren't really the best place if you've lots of variables.  Also people don't like cookies,  so may restrict them.

The ViewState is a great place to store data though.  This is sent as a postback from your web forms and can be used to store reasonable amounts of data.  For example if your application uses several pages to complete a process (e.g. ordering something),  then you can persist data in the ViewState and this will be available when the page is posted back.

Used in the right way,  the ViewState is very effective.